df.to_excel converts Decimal columns to text
I have a DataFrame where some columns use the Decimal datatype. I'd like to export this data to an Excel spreadsheet, keeping the decimal/numeric format. However, my code is converting the columns to textual formats instead.
df['some_col1'] = df['some_col1'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x) if pd.notnull(x) else None)
df['some_col2'] = df['some_col2'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x) if pd.notnull(x) else None)
output = io.BytesIO()
with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    
    # Define number format
    number_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0000'})
    
    # Apply formatting based on column name
    for col_num, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
        if col_name == 'some_col1' or col_name == 'some_col2':  # Specify by column name
              worksheet.set_column(col_num, col_num, None, number_format)

It doesn't work even if I specify the columns directly in set_column ("A:A" for example). You can see this incorrect formatting in the spreadsheet:

How can I export this data with the correct formatting?

Known issue. Here is the Github Issue link: GitHub Issue: decimal to text in Excel
The issue is caused by the Pandas to_excel method where decimal.Decimal values are being saved as text is due to Pandas not recognising it as a numeric type.
To fix this you can modify the decimals to float:
Directly Converting to Float
Instead of casting the decimal and then to float you can directly cast to float.
df['some_col1'] = df['some_col1'].astype('float')
df['some_col2'] = df['some_col2'].astype('float')

This will be recognised as a numeric type and not be text in Excel.

Try changing the column type using:
df['some_col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['some_col1']).apply(lambda x: float(x) if pd.notnull(x) else None)
df['some_col2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['some_col2']).apply(lambda x: float(x) if pd.notnull(x) else None)


Why not .astype("float") instead of the inefficient .apply(...)-lambda combo?
